# Javascript function from HTML

Tags: javascript

I just had a question answered on this issue. With one function it works fine. But with two functions in the javascript files the header and nav section don't show up. This is part of homework assignment where it specifically calls for document.write to be used. Please advise.

```
function displayHeader() {
  document.write(
    "<h1> "
    + "<img src = 'images/PeteBanner.jpg' alt = 'Pistol Pete' / >"
    + "Jason Lemon 's Javascript Website!" 
    + "<img src = 'images/PeteBanner.jpg' alt = 'Pistol Pete' / > </h1>"
  );
};

function displayNav() 
{ 
    document.write("<ul class="nav">" + "
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP02.html">Chp 2</a></li>;" + "
        <li><a href="CSP03.html">Chp 3</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP04.html">Chp 4</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP05.html">Chp 5</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP06.html">Chp 6</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP07.html">Chp 7</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP08.html">Chp 8</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP09.html">Chp 9</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP10.html">Chp 10</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP11.html">Chp 11</a></li>" + "
        <li><a href="CSP12.html">Chp 12</a></li> / > </ul> "); 
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to explain what this is supposed to happening, but what's actually happening. Also, please use the formatting tools to fix your code.

Comment: Load your page. Right-click it in the web browser and choose *View Source* from the menu. Look to see what your functions actually generated. Is it what you expected?

Comment: Also take care that you're not calling `document.write` after the page has loaded; calling `document.write` on a fully loaded page overwrites all existing HTML (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's your code, then you have some errors in the function displayNav().

Note that all of your attributes, such as `class` or `href`, have `"` instead of `\"` or `'`... That causes the javascript interpreter to look for a variable (i.e. `nav`, `index.html`) instead of treating those values as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with double quotation marks.
Use this:

```
function displayNav() {

    document.write('<ul class="nav">'
    + '<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP02.html">Chp 2</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP03.html">Chp 3</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP04.html">Chp 4</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP05.html">Chp 5</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP06.html">Chp 6</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP07.html">Chp 7</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP08.html">Chp 8</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP09.html">Chp 9</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP10.html">Chp 10</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP11.html">Chp 11</a></li>'
    + '<li><a href="CSP12.html">Chp 12</a></li>'
    + '</ul>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, your document.write( using " to express string, but inside your content, it contains " as well.
To solve the problem, you have to change document.write(" to document.write(' as:

```
document.write('<ul class="nav">'
+ '<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP02.html">Chp 2</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP03.html">Chp 3</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP04.html">Chp 4</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP05.html">Chp 5</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP06.html">Chp 6</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP07.html">Chp 7</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP08.html">Chp 8</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP09.html">Chp 9</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP10.html">Chp 10</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP11.html">Chp 11</a></li>'
+ '<li><a href="CSP12.html">Chp 12</a></li> / > </ul> ');
```